# What does き do in this sentence: あんな目に遭ってもなお 気高き兵士のままだ！

Tags: i-adjectives, classical-japanese

I saw this sentence in an episode of *Attack on Titan*, a soldier is having a panic attack and the speaker says

> あんな目に遭ってもなお
> 気高**き**兵士のままだ！

What does き do here? What's the difference from **い**?

> あんな目に遭ってもなお
> 気高**い**兵士のままだ！

Comment: Does this answer you? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/how-does-ki-form-of-i-adjectives-work-e-g-%E6%84%9B%E3%81%97%E3%81%8D

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does -ki form of i-adjectives work? (e.g. 愛しき)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3120/how-does-ki-form-of-i-adjectives-work-e-g-%e6%84%9b%e3%81%97%e3%81%8d) / [What is the ki used for in this sentence? 懐かし き 故郷](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34108/5010) / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53529/5010